# Unable to connect chrome

Tags: google-chrome, docker

I am developing which require some interaction with google chrome . I am running my application inside a docker container. While it is outside docker i m able to connect to chrome browser but when it is inside docker i m getting an error like

```
  ChromeLauncher:error connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:33715 +2ms
  ChromeLauncher Waiting for browser. +0ms
  ChromeLauncher Waiting for browser... +0ms
  ChromeLauncher Waiting for browser..... +511ms
  ChromeLauncher Waiting for browser....... +502ms
  ChromeLauncher Waiting for browser......... +503ms
  ChromeLauncher Waiting for browser........... +502ms
  ChromeLauncher Waiting for browser............. +502ms
  ChromeLauncher Waiting for browser............... +502ms
  ChromeLauncher Waiting for browser................. +503ms
  ChromeLauncher Waiting for browser................... +502ms
  ChromeLauncher Waiting for browser..................... +502ms
  ChromeLauncher Waiting for browser....................... +502ms
  ChromeLauncher Waiting for browser......................... +501ms
  ChromeLauncher Waiting for browser........................... +502ms
  ChromeLauncher Waiting for browser............................. +503ms
  ChromeLauncher Waiting for browser............................... +502ms
  ChromeLauncher Waiting for browser................................. +502ms
  ChromeLauncher Waiting for browser................................... +500ms
  ChromeLauncher Waiting for browser..................................... +502ms
  ChromeLauncher Waiting for browser....................................... +501ms
  ChromeLauncher Waiting for browser......................................... +501ms
  ChromeLauncher Waiting for browser........................................... +502ms
  ChromeLauncher Waiting for browser............................................. +501ms
  ChromeLauncher Waiting for browser............................................... +502ms
  ChromeLauncher Waiting for browser................................................. +503ms
  ChromeLauncher Waiting for browser................................................... +502ms
  ChromeLauncher Waiting for browser..................................................... +502ms
  ChromeLauncher Waiting for browser....................................................... +502ms
  ChromeLauncher Waiting for browser......................................................... +501ms
  ChromeLauncher Waiting for browser........................................................... +502ms
  ChromeLauncher Waiting for browser............................................................. +502ms
  ChromeLauncher Waiting for browser............................................................... +503ms
  ChromeLauncher Waiting for browser................................................................. +502ms
  ChromeLauncher Waiting for browser................................................................... +502ms
  ChromeLauncher Waiting for browser..................................................................... +502ms
  ChromeLauncher Waiting for browser....................................................................... +502ms
  ChromeLauncher Waiting for browser......................................................................... +502ms
  ChromeLauncher Waiting for browser........................................................................... +502ms
  ChromeLauncher Waiting for browser............................................................................. +502ms
  ChromeLauncher Waiting for browser............................................................................... +502ms
  ChromeLauncher Waiting for browser................................................................................. +503ms
  ChromeLauncher Waiting for browser................................................................................... +502ms
  ChromeLauncher Waiting for browser..................................................................................... +502ms
  ChromeLauncher Waiting for browser....................................................................................... +503ms
  ChromeLauncher Waiting for browser......................................................................................... +502ms
  ChromeLauncher Waiting for browser........................................................................................... +502ms
  ChromeLauncher Waiting for browser............................................................................................. +501ms
  ChromeLauncher Waiting for browser............................................................................................... +502ms
  ChromeLauncher Waiting for browser................................................................................................. +502ms
  ChromeLauncher Waiting for browser................................................................................................... +502ms
  ChromeLauncher Waiting for browser..................................................................................................... +502ms
  ChromeLauncher Waiting for browser....................................................................................................... +502ms
  ChromeLauncher:error connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:33715 +2ms
  ChromeLauncher:error Logging contents of /tmp/lighthouse.ZztambY/chrome-err.log +1ms
  ChromeLauncher:error [0207/061816.421061:ERROR:zygote_host_impl_linux.cc(89)] Running as root without --no-sandbox is not supported. See https://crbug.com/638180.
  ChromeLauncher:error  +0ms
Unable to connect to Chrome
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use  [`--add-host`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#managing-etchosts) flag with your `docker run` command when starting the app container:

```
docker run --add-host="chrome:127.0.0.1" <the rest of the command>
```

Then you could access your locally running chrome instance by `chrome` hostname. Of course all this requires that the port you use is actually open (I assume it is since the app runs outside of the container).